# session conflict occurs in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session, proxy, conflict

all users of my site will access it from behind proxy (using TMG application) so they appear to be have the same IP so when two or more users access my site from the same browser the user's data that is displayed for the user based on his session data sometimes is his actual data and some time is the data of one of the currently logged users and i do not know why this behavior occurs?

Comment: Maybe try to save session data to database. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: session table is already used and ION auth library is used also

Comment: Store all necessery data in cookie then ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `sess_match_ip` to false in `./application/config/config.php` file.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is already set and does not work